# Zoom Setting On Google Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/index.php) page to allow users to view markers saved in a MySQL database and to geocode/reverse geocode new marker positions.

I'm able to correctly center the map on the marker which is being loaded from the database, but the problem I'm having is that the map zooms in to it's maximum setting, whereas I would like to be able to set this manually.

I've tried adding another zoom control into my script here:

```
// add marker
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(las[i],lgs[i]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: loc, 
map: window.map,
zoom: 8,
title: nms[i]
});
bounds.extend(loc);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Unfortunately this has no affect. I appreciate that to some this may be a very minor fix, but I've been looking at this for sometime and I just can't seem to find a solution.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong?

**POST UPDATE**

I have worked out a solution using exisitng code and that suggested by @Andrew Leach. The working solution is:

```
// add marker
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(las[i],lgs[i]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: loc, 
map: window.map,            
title: nms[i]
});
bounds.extend(loc);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(16);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the references to the `bounds`.

You add a marker to the map, and create a `LatLngBounds` object which contains *only* that *single* point. You then ask the map to zoom in to fit the bounds into the map's viewport. Fitting a single location into the viewport will always zoom in as far as it can, and even then a single point can never fill the entire viewport.

However, adding `zoom` to the marker options won't work either, because `zoom` is not a valid option. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

Instead, set the map's zoom explicitly, either with `map.setZoom(8)` or by including the `zoom` option in the **map's** options when you set it up.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post, it is greatly appreciated. I found that removing the `bounds` from the script meant that the map didn't center on the marker, so I kept those in, and by adding your suggestion for the `zoom` code I've got the map working fine. I've made an update to my original code to for reference. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, that's because you should be using map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()). That's what Andrew Leach meant by not using a bounds.